# Add multiple Attribute to single product in django oscar

Tags: django, django-oscar

I am trying to add multiple attribute to single product

But i can't find option where to add it from dashboard

can you please guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Oscar Dashboard, look for the **Catalog** tab. It is a drop down with **Product Type** as a menu item. Click on it. Create a new product type if you do not already have one. Click on the product type. Look for **Product attributes**. You can add multiple product attributes of different types(Text, Integer et al.) here.

To summarize Dashboard -> Catalog -> Product Type -> Product attributes